# Ajax rest request url without query string

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, rest

I have a simple flask-restful api, I like to make an ajax request to retrieve some data. But the ajax request contains the data as a query string which makes the url invalid for the api. Here are the codes:

The flask-restful api:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

articles = {"1001":"article1001"}

class Stock(Resource):
    def get(self, article_number):
        return {article_number: articles[article_number]}

api.add_resource(Stock, '/stock/<string:article_number>')
```

the ajax call is:

```
var arg = '1001'
function testApiGet(arg){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {article_number: arg},
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock',
    success: function(data){
      console.log("API works fine")
    }
  })
}
```

Looking at the logs of the localhost server, the ajax tries to request the following url:

```
"GET /stock?article_number=1001 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

While what I want to achieve is a request from ajax to this url:

```
"GET /stock/1001"
```

I have tried changing the ajax request to this, and it works, but I feel this is not the right technique.

```
function testApiGet(arg){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    // I add arg to the url as a normal string.
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock/'+arg, 
    success: function(data){
      console.log("API works fine")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is no other way to send get data without argument passing, You have to try `url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock/'+arg` or change request type to `POST` and pass argument as post data so your request url looks like `"GET /stock/"` something.

Comment: the last one is pretty ok,, no other built-in solution

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a clean way of doing it, but since you have jQuery at hand, you could simplify:

```
var arg = '1001'
function testApiGet(arg){    
  $.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock/'+ arg, function( data ) {
    console.log("API works fine")
  });
}
```

And for good measure, use .done.fail.always:

```
var arg = '1001'
function testApiGet(arg){    
  $.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock/'+ arg)
  .done(function() {
    console.log("API works fine");
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("API DOESN'T work fine");
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "Do this no matter what works or not." );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

It will work with GET request to work with query string with out getting 404.

```
var arg = '1001'
function testApiGet(arg){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {article_number: arg},
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/stock',
    success: function(data){
      console.log("API works fine")
    }
  })
}
```